# Is there a way to get current username and password in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

When I login to a webpage using Basic Auth, is there a way to get the username and password I used to log in with during the session?

I am connecting to a websocket from that page and want to re-use username and password to make sure the ws connection is coming from this user.

Comment: Typically, when the log in takes place you could obtain some kind of _bearer_ token and then use that to authenticate the web socket connection.

Comment: This would be disasterous for security if anybody could just extract your credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. That information is not exposed to JS.

Answer (score 1):

In Simple word "NO".
If you are able to do that in your application or any application then that is a big security concern.